# Using background worker in GTK# to access GUI Elements without Illegal Access Exception

Tags: c#, multithreading, mono, gtk, gtk#

I have a fairly long piece of code that is put in the `Dowork()` of a background worker.
I simply call the `runworkerasync()` when stuff needs to get done.

Im now porting that application to mono(GTK#).Is there any way i can use Background worker to access the GUI Elements?

I tried using Background worker by adding **system.componentmodel** reference.It works.
But in winforms i had to disable ***checkforillegeal cross thread exceptions*** to access GUI elements from background worker.But in GTK# there is no option to do that since i use the GTK window instead of winforms.I get an Illegal Access Exception when trying to access GUI elements is there a similar way to get over this.

> System.AccessViolationException:  Data    Cannot evaluate expression
>   because the thread is stopped in native code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since [Mono 2.4](http://www.mono-project.com/Release_Notes_Mono_2.6) there is support for the [`Task Parallel Library`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which is an abstraction over the [`ThreadPool`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and the recommanded way of executing Background Threads. Mono 3.2.3 also supports the `async/await` keywords, which go alone nicely with the TPL.

Here is a very simple example:

```
Task<int> task = Task.Run( () =>
    {
        int result = 1 + 2;
    }).ContinueWith((task) => 
    {
        // Update GUI Here
    }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

This will offload the calculation to a ThreadPool thread and will eventually return the result to the `Task.Result` property.

If you want to use `BackgroundWorker`, you can register to the `RunWorkerCompleted` event and update your `UserControl` there.

```
var backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker;
backgroundWorker.DoWork += DoWorkMethod
backgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += OnWorkerFinished // Update UI here.
```

Note, in order for the `RunWorkerCompleted` to be invoked on the UI thread, the `BackgroundWorker` has to be **created** on the UI thread!

Comment: Thanks,I have got background worker to work.But there is a problem in accessing GUI elements.I have updated the question.

Comment: Try registering to the `RunWorkerCompleted` event and update your GUI there

Comment: Im unable to understand the Task Parallel Library method.Having problems with background worker.Please see my new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27803194/accessing-system-drawing-bitmap-from-gtk-thread-throws-object-currently-in-use Any help is very much appreciated,in a roadblock now.