# Accessing System.Drawing.Bitmap from GTK# Thread throws Object Currently in use elsewhere exception

Tags: c#, multithreading, mono, gtk, gtk#

Im trying to manipulate an image using system.drawing in GTk#.I want the UI to update the image on screen as soon as the user updates a textbox.To implement this i tried using the background worker from winforms,it worked but when the textbox is updated at a higher speed the application becomes stuck with no error.

So i took a look at multithreading in GTK here http://www.mono-project.com/docs/gui/gtksharp/responsive-applications/ and created a thread .

```
void textboxchanged()
{
    Thread thr = new Thread (new ThreadStart (ThreadRoutine));
    thr.Start ();

  }

  static void ThreadRoutine ()
  {
        LargeComputation ();

  }

  static void LargeComputation ()
  {
    image=new Bitmap(backupimage);
   //Long image processing 
  }
```

It works poorly than the background worker throws up object currently in use elsewhere error here `image=new Bitmap(backupimage);` when the speed of entry in textbox is even a little fast.What im i doing wrong ?

***Update 1 :***

Im not processing the same image using 2 different threads that does 2 different operations at the same time.Im calling the thread that does the same operation before the old thread is complete.As in background worker i need a way to check if the old thread has completed working before launching the new one.So basically what im looking for is a way to check if an instance of the same thread 
is running.In winforms i used to do `if(backgroundworker.isbusy==false) then do stuff`

***Update 2***

***Solution with performance degradation***

As suggested by @voo Replacing the global bitmap helped solve the issue.What i did was instead of using global bitmap.I created a global string(filename).Now i use `img=new Bitmap(filename)`.Tried executing fast as i can no error came up.So inorder to update the GUI i used the invoke as suggested here [mono-project.com/docs/gui/gtksharp/responsive-applications/](http://mono-project.com/docs/gui/gtksharp/responsive-applications/).The thing is no error comes up and image gets updated,but when the typing operation is fast enough there a wait involved. Performance got degraded.This was not the case with background worker.Is there a way to improve performance.

At end of the large image processing operation method i added this to update GUI

```
Gtk.Application.Invoke (delegate {

            MemoryStream istream=new MemoryStream();
            img.Save (istream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
            istream.Position = 0;
            workimagepixbuff = new Gdk.Pixbuf (istream);
            image1.Pixbuf = workimagepixbuff.ScaleSimple (400, 300, Gdk.InterpType.Bilinear);

        });
        // cannot directly convert Bitmap to Pixbuff,so doing this
```

Comment: I'll use my Crystal ball (because no idea about gtk at all) and say that gtk like pretty much every other UI toolkit doesn't like you updating the GUI from a thread other than the main thread and offers some way to queue operations on the main thread street the expensive computation is finished.

Comment: @Voo Im not updating the UI in the thread.Im just processing the image.

Comment: Can you give use the exact exception? I just grep-ped both libgdiplus and mono sources and i could not find any references to the text you provided. Or are you running on Windows?

Comment: @fog Im running on windows.The exception was system exception-Object currently in use elsewhere,i will update the exact details tomorrow,i don't have access to the pc now.I think it was System.InvalidOperationException

Comment: Are you accessing the same image from multiple threads?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov No,when the thread runs.Its the only thing that uses the image.

Comment: Could you post some more code?? 

And are you showing the image in a 'Picturebox' or are you drawing it via another way??

Basically what happens is you've got the main GUI thread and your creating a new thread to create (update) a bitmap.
So you've got two threads (atleast)

What is the backup image variable?? Where does it originate from?

Comment: @Blaatz0r im not accessing the user interface from this thread.I had the code for updating the ui at the end removed it for testing.I have declared 'backupimage' in the main class,so that it can be accessed globally.Also i create a new instance of this backupimage when a user clicks on an image shown in the ui.But these two things are not linked together nor work simultaneously.The error only comes up when the thread is executed repeatedly fast enough.Had the same problem in winforms tackled using if(backgroundworker.isbusy()==false).Same thing needs to be done here.Will post more code.

Comment: So where's the code for actually swapping the background image that you don't show in your GUI code with the one you do show? How do you avoid two of your background threads being created and both working on the same global variable?

Comment: @Voo Im not swapping the image,removed the code thinking it was causing the problem.I dont avoid both threads working on the same variable,how to avoid this?

Comment: @techno Well that seems likely to be the problem, particularly considering the problem description. Don't use global variables, they're error prone for many reasons. Easiest thing is to use a local variable and do all the work on that and just return it. You can still set it afterwards.

Comment: @Voo Thanks that was the problem.What i did was instead of using global bitmap.I created a global string(filename).Now i use img=new Bitmap(filename).Tried executing fast as i can no error came up.So inorder to update the GUI i used the invoke as suggested here http://www.mono-project.com/docs/gui/gtksharp/responsive-applications/.The thing is no error comes up and image gets updated,but when the typing operation is fast enough there a wait involved. Performance got degraded.This was not the case with background worker.Is there a way to improve performance.Please see the edit above

Comment: The global string sounds like at best a bandaid - much better to just pass the filename to the string when you create it, avoids the race condition (although you really should think about what should happen if you have several threads anyhow, this isn't really clear). I don't know GTK, but is there any reason to do the memory reading and scaling in the GUI thread instead of just the assignment? Seems pretty weird.

Comment: @voo  The filename is created when the user clicks.These 2 events are separate there is no way other than to use a global variable

Comment: @Voo I tried putting just the assignment in the GUI thread.Now things are much better.Thanks.Do you mind adding this as an answer?

Comment: @techno glad to hear, but I must admit these days I don't care about reputation at all and am just too lazy to write up answers. Pity for the bounty though - you might give it to the new user who tried to help you.

Comment: @Voo I get it :) Given it to the new user.

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is that you are processing an image at two places (two threads) on the same time and the image operation in .Net (GDI speaking) does not allow this.
Because you did not provided very much information I'm just guessing here.

When manipulating bitmap images in GDI, there are BitmapData behind the scene that needs to be locked and unlocked. This mechanism just make the picture available in memory for read/write. But AFAIK when you lock a BitmapData that is already locked you get a similar exception : System.InvalidOperationException, Bitmap region is already locked.

To me it sounds like you are getting this kind of error, but with other words because you are not explicitly locking bitmap data bits. GDI just tell you : "I would have to lock bitmap data bits but I can't because the object is already used (locked) elsewhere."

The solution here may be to try to **synchronize** bitmap usage (where bits locking may be involved) between thread whenever they may occur. So you may want to use the **lock** keyword or a similar mechanism:

So try something that looks like the following:

```
private static object _imageLock = new object();
static void LargeComputation ()
  {
     lock(_imageLock)
     {
       image=new Bitmap(backupimage);
       //Long image processing ...
     }
  }

  static void AnotherImageOperationSomewhereElse()
  {
       lock(_imageLock)
       {
          //Another image processing on backupImage or something derived from it...
       }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.Im not processing the same image using 2 different threads that does 2 different operations at the same time.Im calling the thread that does the same operation before the old thread is complete.As in background worker i need a way to check if the old thread has completed working before launching the new one.So basically what im looking for is a way to check if an instance of the same thread is running.

Comment: You seems telling that the 'new' thread is running while the 'old' thread has not finished. If so, you may be processing the image in two different threads. By the way if you do not want parallelizing (threading) processing between 'new' and 'old' threads you may not want using threads here. Nevertheless if you try locking section of bitmap processing in your 'old' and 'new' thread my solution should prevent the exception that is raised. And it's funny because I just had the same exception today on a project I'm developing and I solved it by syncing threads with the lock keyword ;-)

Comment: I don't understand  how this lock mechanism works.What exactly  is image lock what does lock (imagelock) do . Did you see my update #2

Comment: @techno, I saw your update and I'm convinced you are not on the right track here. I could not give you detailed explanation here about locking mechanism but a simple search on msdn will give you everything you need to know. Basically you should just know that images are bit-mapped in memory and modifying this memory requires to 'lock' the corresponding memory place. Because of this requirement Gdi images are not thread-safe "out of the box" : you have to deal with the fact that more than one thread could try to lock the memory and fails if this is already locked. Here come the lock keyword.

Comment: The lock keyword will block (pause execution of) any thread that try to enter a lock {} section while a thread is already running it. So it's a synchronizing mechanism between threads and is what you need here to prevent multiple bit-mapped memory 'lock'.

Comment: Thanks.I understand the concept you are telling me.But in my case the issue has been solved by update #2 .But thanks for providing details about synchronization. Im awarding you the bounty half for this and half since you are a new user on SO.